# Delete first and last lines from string

Tags: php, string, file, lines

I have string named $post (for example) which contain data bellow. I want to remove lines until first "TEXT" (I don't know how many tags will there be so no exact lines are possible). I also want to remove all lines bellow last "TEXT".

```
<div id="content">
                    <div class="date">2013-02-11      16:19:57</div>
                    <h2 class="storytitle"><a href="p.php?slug=SOMESLUG">PRPHAHAHAH</a></h2>

                    <!-- TAGS -->
                    <div class="tags"><a href="/tag/">slug1</a> <a href="/tag/">slug2</a> <a href="/tag/">slug3</a> </div>TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
<br />
<pre><code>1
2
3
4
5
</code></pre><br />
<br />
TEXT

                    <p id="comments" class="separator-story">
                        <!-- <div class="comments"></a href="/post/Somepost" -->
                    </p>
                    </div>
```

The only thing I want to have in my string is this:

```
TEXT<br />
    TEXT<br />
    TEXT<br />
    TEXT<br />
    TEXT<br />
    <br />
    <pre><code>1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    </code></pre><br />
    <br />
    TEXT
```

Note:

- I don't know how many tags user will have, nor how many lines I have
  to remove from start, which at the end mean I don't know where first
  "TEXT" start.
- I don't know how huge post will be, nor from where do
  I start deleting.
- I only know that there are 5 lines at the end that
  I need them removed.   I only know that tags finish with  and
  last lines start with

  I don't know what will be first letter/word of the text I need to extract (TEXT is just example)

Reference:
[Explode (PHP)](http://php.net/explode)
[Array Slice (PHP)](http://php.net/array_slice)

Answer (score 1):

Just find the **first** occurrence and **last** occurrence, and use those to build your string:

```
$input  = (your input string);
$search = 'TEXT';
$first  = strpos($input, $search);
$last   = strrpos($input, $search);

$final  = substr($input, $first, strlen($input) - $first - $last);
```

Reference [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos), [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr).

Comment: Ah, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I just added a new bullet, check it out. I don't know what will be first letter/word. Thanks for the reference and answer tho.

Comment: If you don't know the `TEXT` word we're looking for, what's the logic to determine it?

Comment: Last tag finish with "</a> </div>"

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
$test= <<<EOM
<div id="content">
                    <div class="date">2013-02-11      16:19:57</div>
                    <h2 class="storytitle"><a href="p.php?slug=SOMESLUG">PRPHAHAHAH</a></h2>

                    <!-- TAGS -->
                    <div class="tags"><a href="/tag/">slug1</a> <a href="/tag/">slug2</a> <a href="/tag/">slug3</a> </div>TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
TEXT<br />
<br />
<pre><code>1
2
3
4
5
</code></pre><br />
<br />
TEXT

                    <p id="comments" class="separator-story">
                        <!-- <div class="comments"></a href="/post/Somepost" -->
                    </p>
                    </div>
EOM;


$tok = strtok($test, "\n");

$found_start = false;
$found_middle = false;
$found_end = false;

$string_start = "";
$string_middle = "";
$string_end = "";

while ($tok !== false) {
    if ( strpos(str_replace(" ", "", $tok), "TEXT" ) === 0) {
      if(!$found_middle){
        //middle not found yet, so still looking for start
        $string_start = $string_start . $tok;
        $found_start = true;
      } else { 
        //middle found and this token starts with the key, so it is the end
        $string_end = $tok;
        $found_end = true;
      }
    } else if($found_start) {
        $string_middle = $string_middle . $tok;
        $found_middle = true;
    }
    if(!$found_end){
      $tok = strtok("\n");
    } else {
      $tok = false;
    }
}

echo $string_start . $string_middle . $string_end;
```

Comment: Ouch, that code is huge. As you may see in last bullet in my question, I don't know how the text starts. I don't know if there will be "TEXT" paragraph at first. But here is upvote for you, thanks for contribution!